# Запуск программы на python

Tags: python

Я только учусь на python и решил сделать реальную супер простую прогу на пк с помощью wxwidget. Написал код и сохранил в формате .py. Что дальше делать, чтобы при запуске запускалась программа, а то я нажимаю на файл и заходит в командую строку и вылетает?

```
import wx

app = wx.App()
wnd = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "I'm the title")
wnd.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: запустите приложение из командной строки.

Answer (score 1):

Первый способ - через командную строку. Последовательность действий:

1) Откройте командную строку (*cmd* для Win или *terminal* для MacOS/Linux)

2) командой *cd* перейдите в каталог с вашим скриптом

3) запустите его командой *>python script_name.py*

Второй способ через различные IDE и текстовые редакторы.
Например откройте скрипт в Sublime Text 3 и нажмите ctrl+B (cmd+B на маке)

Comment: И не забудьте установить соответствующую библиотеку https://www.wxpython.org/download.php