# Запуск скрипта на Python через CMD

Tags: python-3.x, cmd

Пытаюсь запустить простенькую программу на Python через командную строку.
[Запуск программы на python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/570263/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python) - пробовала, не помогло:

> can't open file 'Hi.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Ввожу полный путь и так `/`, и так `\`, вот текст ошибки:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Python\Hi.py
>                                                     ^
>   SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Вводила просто `python\Hi.py`, всё об одном.
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Возможно вы не указали путь до папки с файлом(cd путь)?

Comment: Указывала через cd C:/
C:\>python Hi.py
(null): can't open file 'Hi.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Файл Hi.py в каком каталоге лежит?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Python

Comment: cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Python, а потом python Hi.py?

Comment: Сейчас скопировала чисто ваш путь, и пошло.

Подскажите, почему не работает через чисто python Hi.py?

Comment: @Annushka потому что в вашем варианте Python будет искать Hi.py в рабочей директории, то есть там, где вы его запустили.